# Why does jquery submit my ajax form twice?

Tags: ajax, jquery

When my form is submitted php will return `false` if it doesn't like the values contained in `field1` and `field2`. If it does like those fields, then it will return `true`. If a user submits the form and php returns `false`, then an alert appears. After closing the alert window, if the user immediately enters new (good) data into those fields and submits the form again, then the form is somehow submitted twice. Why? How can I fix this?

```
$("form#myForm").on('submit',function() 
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: 'myfile.php',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: 
        {
            field1:$("input[name=field1]").val(),
            field2:$("input[name=field2]").val()
        },
        success: function(data)
        {
            if(data == false) 
            {
                alert('hello world');
            } 
            else 
            {
                // stuff
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: It seems to work on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ujinon/3/edit), it only makes one request per submit. To make it run on jsbin, I changed `POST` to `GET`, set the url to `#`, and replaced the `data == false` with `true`. HTH

Answer (score 4):

The same question was asked in 2014 ([jquery ajax form submits twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195483/jquery-ajax-form-submits-twice)).

`e.preventDefault()` on its own works for buttons and anchor links but didn't work for me when submitting a form (identical to Nancy 's code above).

I had to add `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` just before my ajax post.  This stopped the ajax call from being submitted twice.

Comment: The OP asked why though, and I'm also curious

Comment: I don't know why this happens unfortunately.  Nancy asked "Why? How can I fix this?", so I managed to answer how to fix it, but not the why.

Comment: I figured out why it was happening with my code. The javascript tags on the <head> were duplicated, running the script (and thus attaching the hook) twice.

Answer (score 2):

add this code after below, before `return false`

```
$('#myForm').unbind('submit');
 return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you're doing the ajax post you'll need to disable the default submit button behavior. See http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/