# Ajax form submitting twice?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I couldn't find the mistake but it submit form twice . Please help me what i missed in this .

```
    $('#supplierForm').on('submit', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if ($(this).valid()) {
                    $.ajax({
                        async: false,
                        data: $("#supplierForm").serialize(),
                        url:  '{{ url('supplier_edit_new') }}',
                        type: 'POST',
                        success: function (data) {
                                window.location.reload();

                        }
                    });
                }
                return false;
            })

;
```

For validating script

```
$("document").ready(function(){

    $('#supplierForm').validate({
        errorClass: 'help-block',
        rules: {
            'line1': "required",
            'line2': "required",
            'suburb': "required",
            'state' : "required",
            'country':"required",


        },
        messages: {

            'line1':{required: "Please enter supplier's address."},
            'line2':{required: "Please enter supplier's address."},
            'suburb':{required: "Please enter  supplier's suburb."},
            'state':{required: "Please select a state"},
            'country':{required: "Please enter country"},
            'postcode':{required: "Please enter postcode"},

        },

        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).parent().parent().removeClass("success").addClass("error");
        },

        unhighlight: function (element) {
            $(element).parent().parent().removeClass("error").addClass("success");
        }
    }); // validate
});
```

For html

```
{{ form_widget(form.submit,{'attr':{'class':'btn btn-primary btn-large btn-style','value':'Save changes'} }) }} 
it generate 

<button id="ovc_bundle_productbundle_supplier_submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-style" value="Save changes" name="ovc_bundle_productbundle_supplier[submit]" type="submit">Save / Update Details</button>
```

Comment: i think you are  clicking twice

Comment: add e.returnValue = false;

Comment: @NitishKumar `e.preventDefault` and `return false` are equivalent.

Comment: Maybe you're binding the event handler multiple times? There's nothing in the code you've posted that would call it twice, it has to be elsewhere.

Comment: can you update the question with your HTML code too?

Comment: @vijay4vijju can you update the question with your HTML code too? If you have Button type "submit" in your html code then change it to simple button and it should be fine. see this thread for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195483/jquery-ajax-form-submits-twice.

Comment: @spooky Update html button

Answer (score 3):

Try this to prevent binding the event multiple times,

```
$('#supplierForm').off('submit');
$('#supplierForm').on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ($(this).valid()) {
                $.ajax({
                    async: false,
                    data: $("#supplierForm").serialize(),
                    url:  '{{ url('supplier_edit_new') }}',
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function (data) {
                            window.location.reload();

                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        })
```

Comment: If we off the submit . I won't submit even once ?

Comment: You `off` submit and same time `on` it again. So it only `off` multiple event bindings..