# Why does Ajax form submit twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Why does the below script cause the form to submit twice?  I can't figure this out, even after trying other solutions posted around the internet.  Submitting twice is causing duplicate entries in the database.  Thank you in advance for looking into this!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#form-error').hide();
    $("#form-submit").click(function(){
        $("#form").submit();
    });
});

$('#form').submit(function(e) {
            register();
    e.preventDefault();
    });

function register()
{               
    jQuery.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'actions/add.php',
        data: $('#form').serialize(),
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(msg){

            if(parseInt(msg.status)==1)
            {
                window.location=msg.txt;
            }
            else if(parseInt(msg.status)==0)
            {
                error(1,msg.txt);
            }
        }
    });

}               

function hideshow(el,act)
    {
    if(act) 
        {
        $('#'+el).hide(0).slideDown(500, 'linear');
        }
    else $('#'+el).hide();
    }   

function error(act,txt)
    {
    if(txt) 
        {
        $('#form-error').html(txt);
        }
    $('#form-error').hide(0).slideDown(500, 'linear');
    }
</script>
```

HTML Form:

```
 <form id="form">
            <p>First Name:</p>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" />
            <p>Last Name:</p>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" />
            <p>E-Mail Address:</p>
            <input type="text" name="emailaddress" />
            <p>Sequence Assignment:</p>
            <select name="sequence">
                <option value="1">Default Sequence</option>
            </select>
            <button id="form-submit">Add User</button>
            <p id="form-error"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: $("#form").submit();  and Query.ajax({
        method: 'POST',

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery AJAX form submits twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195483/jquery-ajax-form-submits-twice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are duplicated event listeners for the submit event:

1. When submit button clicked:

```
$("#form-submit").click(function(){
   $("#form").submit();
});
```

2. When form is submitted:

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
            register();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

You need only one of them.

Change your code like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#form-error').hide();
    $('#form').submit(function(e) {
        register();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

function register()
{
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: Worked!  Thanks so much!  Javascript isn't my forte, as you can probably tell.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to this. If you just single click on the button does it enter duplicate data?

The way I got around it is once the click happened I disabled the button until after the Ajax call.

```
function register()
{      
    //disable button         
    jQuery.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'actions/add.php',
        data: $('#form').serialize(),
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(msg){

            if(parseInt(msg.status)==1)
            {
                window.location=msg.txt;
            }
            else if(parseInt(msg.status)==0)
            {
                error(1,msg.txt);
            }
        }
    });
    //Enable Button
}
```

Another option would be to do some checks in the php code that submits it to the database to see if that data already exists.