# Debugging jquery handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

This question is a followup of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33110233/preventing-jquery-ajax-call-from-sending-form-data-twice) one. I have created a [simple example](https://jsfiddle.net/8g0rvgnt/5/) to check how code is executed within the handler. For the form

```
<form id="calendar_id" method="post">
    Insert date: <input id="date_id" type="text" name="l_date" required>
</form>
```

I'm trying to retrieve the fields using the following javascript:

```
function get_form_data_uid($form) {
    var unindexed_array = $form.serializeArray();
    var indexed_array = {};

    $.map(unindexed_array, function (n, i) {
        indexed_array[n['name']] = n['value'];
    });

    indexed_array['uid'] = 'badbfadbbfi';

    return indexed_array;
}

$("#calendar_id").submit(function (e) {
    var uri, method, formId, $form, form_data;
    // Prevent default submit
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    uri = "/";
    method = "POST";
    formId = "#calendar_id";

    $form = $(formId);
    form_data = get_form_data_uid($form);

    alert("form_data " + form_data);

    // Set-up ajax call
    var request = {
        url: uri,
        type: method,
        contentType: "application/json",
        accepts: "application/json",
        cache: false,
        // Setting async to false to give enough time to initialize the local storage with the "token" key
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        data: form_data
    };
    // Make the request
    $.ajax(request).done(function (data) { // Handle the response
        // Attributes are retrieved as object.attribute_name
        console.log("Data from change password from server: " + data);
        alert(data.message);
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { // Handle failure
        console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
        console.log("AJAX error on changing password: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
    });

});
```

However, the code within the handler is not executed (the alert is not shown). Why?

**Edit:**

The code works [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8g0rvgnt/9/) but not in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

At least, you are calling a function `get_form_data_with_token()` which is not defined anywhere in your posted code. Perhaps you meant to call your `get_form_data_uid()`.

Would have just made this a comment, but apparently cannot.

Comment: I've made a mistake when copying the code. The alert isn't shown regardless.

Comment: All right, indeed your fiddle seems to fail with an error even after I fix the function name. However, when I then copy the corrected code verbatim to this Codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BodXRp , it does in fact show the alert as expected.

Comment: Oh, your fiddle (after the fix) only failed because you had not included jQuery as a library, but use it in your code. After these two fixes, the fiddle does show the alert. ( https://jsfiddle.net/8g0rvgnt/7/ )

Comment: It's working on jsfiddle but not in my browser. I have no idea why.