# jquery validate not being honored - browser submitting form instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, submit

I have seen @Sparky's answer and sample jsFiddle to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625195/jquery-validator-plugin-ajax-submitting-not-working) question, and to my mind I have the right html and javascript in place, but still the browser is submitting the form.

I have this html:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "ClientWarehouseRequest", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
        {
    <!-- many form inputs here -->
    <div class="buttons-wrap">
                <input type="hidden" name="SubmitButtonValue" id="SubmitButtonValue" />
                <input class="k-button" type="submit" value="Post" name="SubmitButton" />
                @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", controllerName: null, routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "k-button", style = "vertical-align: bottom;" })
                <input class="k-button" type="submit" value="Save" name="SubmitButton" />
            </div>

        }
```

with this javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('form').validate({
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                var postingWindow = $("#postingDialogWindow").data("kendoWindow");
                postingWindow.title("Posting Client Request...");
                postingWindow.open();

                $.ajax({
                    url: form.action,
                    type: form.method,
                    data: $(form).serialize()
                })
                .success(function (result) {
                    if (result.success) {
                        window.alerts.info(result.message, true);
                        window.location.replace(result.redirecturl);
                    }
                    else {
                        window.alerts.error(result.error);
                    }
                })
                .fail(function (result) {
                    //window.alerts.error(result);
                    var result = $.parseJSON(result.responseText);
                    window.alerts.error(result.errorMessage);
                })
                .always(function (data) {
                    postingWindow.close();
                });
                return false;
            },
            invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
                alert('invalid');
            }
        });
}
```

Yet when I click on the of the submit buttons, the browser is submitting the form as a full postback.  I need the form to submit via the $.ajax call inside the validate() function instead.  What am I missing?

Comment: Is there a `e.preventDefault();` in your click handler for the submit button?

Comment: mmm there is no click handler for the submit button (feeling sheepish)?  what else would I put into such a handler other than e.preventDefault();?

Comment: Notice the way it's done in the question you referenced.  There is a `.submit()` that does the `preventDefault()` then executes the ajax call.  You want the same pattern.  Basically, you want to say "when this element is clicked, prevent the normal behavior and do my custom function instead."

Comment: Actually I'm not seeing that.  Not in the code of the question...nor in the code of the jsFiddle referenced in the question...there is no click handler for any button, in which the form submit is called.  What am I missing?